# ST_PixelAsPolygons rasterio

Tags: python, shapes, pixel, geotiff, rasterio

Is there a way to perform a similar function such as ST_PixelAsPolygons using rasterio?
I am aware of rasterio.features.shapes but that would output the shape of similar pixels instead of the geometry of all pixels. How could I get the polygons and values of all pixels?

Comment: pinging @sgillies - perhaps he could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rasterio/transform.py](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/rasterio/transform.py) provides an `xy(transform, rows, cols, offset)` function which returns the location of the grid cell at (row,col).

The offset parameter allows you to specify each "corner" of the cell using `'ul'`, `'ur'`, `'ll'`, `'lr'`.

You can then get the rectangular coordinates of each cell in your transform:

```
rows = [i for i in range(height) for j in range(width)]
cols = [j for i in range(height) for j in range(width)]
corners = []
for offset in ['ul','ur', 'lr', 'll']:
  xs, ys = rasterio.transform.xy(transform,rows,cols,offset)
  corners.append(zip(xs,ys))
cell_rects = zip(*corners)
cell_rects_with_indices = [
    ((row,col), rect) 
    for row,col,rect in zip(rows, cols, cell_rects)
]
```